# Page Load time Testing - How to delay page load?

Tags: html

I've created two identical HTML web pages. I need one to load in 15 seconds and the other to load as fast as possible.

Is there some kind of code snippet i can include in my webpage that predictably slows down a web page load by 15 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps you're using Bootstrap**? Some javascript frameworks/libraries take up much more time. If you want less loading times, try to minimize your code as much as you can. You could also try to avoid code like this:

```
<script>
myVar1.redo.undo.function.operation()
myVar1.redo.undo.function.operation()
myVar1.redo.undo.function.operation()
myVar1.redo.undo.function.operation()
myVar1.redo.undo.function.operation()
</script>
```

Instead, do this:

```
<script>
function operation() {
  myVar1.redo.undo.function.operation()
}
operation()
operation()
operation()
operation()
operation()
```

This is why it's good to use functions to minimize your code.